# JQuery ui. tag a as simple link

Tags: jquery-ui, hyperlink

I use JQuery ui and I don't understand how make a simple link
with a jquery ui created button!

[image]

Help me please make simple link.

Comment: fack... I use $( "input[type=submit], a, button" ).button(); ...

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for. Are you asking how to make a simple `<a href="...">` tag?

Comment: I solved my problem left that code